# How to verify check box is checked with webdriver.io using element.isSelected()

Tags: webdriver-io

[image]Trying to find out if the check box is checked using webdriver.io

XPATH: //*[@id="PageToolbar__i11_btnChkSubmitted"]

using element.isSelected()

Does not work it returns 'false' regardless if the box is checked.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will rewrite my answer since I now noticed that "checked" is part of value atribute.

You need to first parse that value atribute, that's how you get to "checked" property.

```js
const el = $('#PageToolbar__i11_btnChkSubmitted');
const valueAttr = el.getAttribute('value');
const checkedValue = JSON.parse(value).checked;
```

---

I also used just if instead of xPath, it's more readable. Your xPath is not necessary here, plus all you do is use id in that xPath anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that and it returned "null"

Comment: Welcome. If it solved your problem, you can mark my answer as a solution.

Comment: No, that is not the result I am expecting. I need to see it toggle between true and false

Comment: Is the attribute there if it's not checked? Does it have value "false"? Because I don't see that in your question.

Comment: Once I check the check box, the content of "checked: true" if not checked checked: false" in HTML

Comment: Ok, I see why. It's part of value attribute, it's not a separate attribute checked. So you need to parse atribute value that seems to be formatted as JSON. I updated my answer.

Comment: Correct, How do I do this. [0-0] patientactinactfalse enable is: true
[0-0] patientactinactfalse attribute is: {"text":"Show Inactive","value":"","checked":false,"target":"","navigateUrl":"","commandName":"","commandArgument":"","autoPostBack":true,"selectedToggleStateIndex":1,"validationGroup":null,"readOnly":false}

Comment: How do I parse from "checked"? Please advise. Thank you

Comment: I updated my answer, just read it there. It should work.

Comment: That worked, Thank you. Here is the final code: const el = $('//*[@id="PageToolbar__i11_btnChkSubmitted_ClientState"]');
    const valueAttr = el.getAttribute('value');
    const checkedValue = JSON.parse(valueAttr).checked;
    console.log('checked value is:', checkedValue);